# In normed space, can a countable dense subset in closed unit ball of X be finite?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space, let $B_X$ be a closed unit ball of X, and let $C$ be a countable dense subset of $B_X$. Then is that possible $C$ is finite? If possible why?

Thank you!!

Comment: This is possible if and only if $X$ is zero-dimensional. Note that a finite subset of a Hausdorff space is closed, so if it's dense in the unit ball then it must be equal to the unit ball.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If the unit ball is defined by norm less than or equal to $1$ then this is false even for one dimensional space.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had the unit ball confused with the unit sphere.

Comment: I am sorry guys. I don't understand. Could you be more specific? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a normed space, so it is Hausdorff. In particular, $C$ finite implies $C$ is closed.

$C$ dense means by definition $C = \bar C = B_X $. Thus $B_X$ is finite.

For any non-trivial vector-space, any subset with non-empty interior is infinite. Hence it is only possible when $X$ has dimension $0$.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get one thing why for any non-trivial vector-space, any subset with non-empty interior is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Only if $X=\{0\}.$ If $X\ne \{0\}$ let $p\in X$ and let $\overline {B(p,1)}$ be a closed unit ball. Let $0\ne q\in X.$  Let $q'=q/\|q\|.$ Let $n\in \Bbb N.$ Then $$F(n)= \{B(p+q'(4j+1)/4n\; , 1/4n) : j\in \{0,...,n-1\}\}$$ is a family of pair-wise disjoint sets (by the Triangle Inequality) with $n$ members. Members of $F(n)$ are open in $X$ and are subsets of $B(p,1),$ so if $C$ is dense in $B(p,1)$  then $C$ intersects each member of $F(n).$ So for every $n\in \Bbb N,$ there are at least $n$ members of $C.$

Remark: We could also take  $F=\{B(p+4^{-n}q',4^{-n-1}): n\in \Bbb N\},$ an infinite pair-wise disjoint family of open balls that are subsets of $B(p,1)$ and observe that $C$ must intersect every member of $F.$